Is Using Floored Dates as a Feature in Predictive Models a Good Idea?
I’m working on a predictive modeling project and considering using a Floored Date Feature to capture broader temporal patterns in my data. The idea is to round the observation date to a specified granularity G (e.g., day, week, month) using date-specific functions like pd.Timestamp.floor in Python. This approach aims to simplify the temporal information, reducing noise from exact dates, prevent data leakage overfitting, while still capturing important trends over various time scales.
My Questions:

Is using floored dates as a feature in predictive models a good practice?
Have others explored or validated this approach in practical applications?
What are the potential pitfalls or best practices I should be aware of when implementing this feature?

Additional Details:
Definition:
The Floored Date Feature rounds the date of the observation to a specified granularity G using functions like pd.Timestamp.floor. For example, if G is set to ‘W’ for week, all dates are rounded down to the start of their respective weeks.
class DateFloorTransformer(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, column, granularity='D'):
        self.column = column
        self.granularity = granularity

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        X = X.copy()
        X[self.column] = X[self.column].dt.floor(self.granularity)
        return X

# Define the pipeline
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('date_floor', DateFloorTransformer(column='date')),
    ('model', RandomForestTree())
])

# Initialize GridSearchCV
grid_search = GridSearchCV(
    estimator  = pipeline,
    cv         = TimeSeriesSplit(n_splits=5),
    param_grid = {
        'date_floor__granularity': ['D', '7D', 'W', 'M']
    })

Motivation:

Simplification: Reduces the precision of date data to focus on broader temporal trends, minimizing noise from exact dates while capturing important patterns over various time scales.
Tunable Granularity: The granularity G (e.g., ‘D’ for day, ‘W’ for week, ‘M’ for month) can be optimized using time series cross-validation to find the best level of temporal aggregation for prediction.

Pros (as I believe):

Captures Temporal Patterns: Helps in identifying trends without overwhelming the model with exact date details.
Flexibility in Granularity: G can be adjusted to adapt to different time scales based on the data.
Noise Reduction: Discards unnecessary time precision that might introduce noise and lead to overfitting.
Balances Long and Short-Term Trends: Allows the model to learn both broad patterns and fluctuations over the selected time scale.

Cons (& How They Can Be Addressed):

Loss of Fine-Grained Temporal Information: Important details might be lost due to rounding.

Solution: Include additional temporal features like day of the week, month, or special event indicators to capture finer patterns.


Overfitting to Historical Data: The model might overfit to outdated trends.

Solution: Use time series cross-validation to select the optimal G and implement monitoring mechanisms to detect concept drift.


Granularity Selection Challenges: An inappropriate G might miss relevant patterns.

Solution: Conduct exploratory data analysis to understand inherent cycles and test different granularities systematically.


Concept Drift Sensitivity: The model may fail to capture new patterns if trends change over time.

Solution: Monitor model performance over time and retrain the model when significant changes are detected.


Data Leakage Risks: Improper handling could lead to data leakage.

Solution: Ensure proper time-based train-test splits using time series cross-validation methods.



I’m particularly interested in any experiences, studies, or best practices related to using floored dates as a feature in predictive models. Your insights and suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Yes, totally people do this; I haven't seen the terminology "floored dates" but any good intro to time series will discuss using the day of week, month of year, hour of day, etc as variables.

@John But that's not what a "floored date" is: you are referring to the offset relative to a floored date.  The principal general concern about truncating any data is the loss of information.  Whether that is offset by simplicity of the analysis or interpretability of its results is a case-by-case issue.

@whuber, correct.
The purpose of flooring the data is so the model doesn't overfit to that feature.

@JPN I don't believe this has got anything to do with timeseries. At least for me this sounds like an issue with tree based models on continuous data (of which time is one case), as such I would have thought  it might be something better addressed by regularisation parameters ( eg minimum Gain parameters). John Maddens suggestion of adding day of week etc is good practise- since asssuming there is eg a Monday effect, the tree doesn't have to split every single monday in the datetime variable

See https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68834/17230.
